# car is 2012 Nissan Quest, intelligent key shows no key on screen

Tags: nissan, fob, smartkey, quest

car is 2012 Nissan Quest, intelligent key shows no key on screen but I still can start the car when I put the intelligent key close to start stop button, I replace battery but still doing the same